# stop overflow of img element html

Tags: html, css, image

I want to stop the images on the far right from leaking outside the right padding.

The fourth image should stop on the same axis as the red block above it.[image]

Does that make sense?

```html
<div style="margin: 0 15px;height: 40px; background-color: red">

</div>
<div style="padding: 0 15px;height: 400px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `padding: 0 15px` use `margin: 0 15px` to match the other div

Answer (score 2):

Use `margin` instead of `padding`.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 15px;height: 40px; background-color: red">

</div>
<div style="margin: 0 15px;height: 400px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
</div>
```